How can I make it so that when I click an icon, a window with information appears?
There is an icon in the program; by clicking on it, a window with information should appear on top of the program.
How can this be implemented?
import flet as ft

def main(page: ft.page):
    page.title = "Тренировка интуиции"
    page.window_width = 400.00
    page.window_height = 500.00
    page.window_resizable = False

    def info(e):
        # info text
        pass


    page.add(ft.Row([ft.IconButton(ft.icons.HELP, on_click=info)], alignment=ft.alignment.center))

ft.app(target=main)

Please tell me, I’ve been studying recently

Try looking at the Tkinter library. It has many useful features that should allow you to implement what is needed.

import flet as ft

def main(page: ft.page):
    page.title = "Тренировка интуиции"
    page.window_width = 400.00
    page.window_height = 500.00
    page.window_resizable = False

Build info dialog with using  AlertDialog. Add action to close your dialog. Content is the main content in pop-up.
    def info(e):
        diaolog = ft.AlertDialog(title=ft.Text("Information"),
            content=ft.Text("Test Text"),
            actions=[ft.TextButton(text="Close", on_click=close_diaolog)],
            open=True,
            
        )
        
        page.dialog = diaolog 
        page.update()    
        

Built close_diaolog to close dialog after click Close.
    def close_diaolog(e):
        page.dialog.open = False
        page.update()
        
    page.add(ft.Row([ft.IconButton(ft.icons.HELP, on_click=info)], alignment=ft.alignment.center))

        
ft.app(target=main)

